# Why did I just lose 2 points?

Tags: support, down-votes

On my reputation, it says reputation for today is -2...but I can't find what would have caused that, and I have a total history of 0 down votes, so I don't even know how I could have gotten -2. If I lost an upvote, that should be -5.

Comment: Go to stackoverflow.com/reputation, and see what your audit says. Did you unaccept an answer that you accepted yesterday?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the last reputation change I can see are from September 24.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A non-answer located here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297549/preserving-original-button-id-when-using-yui-2-button/7505649#7505649

> You can try using jQuery instead of YUI? ;)

was downvoted  That's where the rep was lost.  The answer was deleted by a mod in response to a flag as it isn't an answer.

Or, at least it wasn't an answer as soon as comments were rolled into the system...

Comment: Oh ok - so why doesn't it show up in my reputation history?

Comment: @jbyrd - Because it's been deleted. If you do a reputation recalculation - on the `\reputation` page - you'll get the 2 points back. However, you will probably lose more due to other deleted posts where you were up-voted.

Comment: Aha - didn't know about the \reputation page - thanks! In my case, I gained 6 points by triggering a recalc.