# Why can I not see my approved suggested edits on posts that have been deleted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

I recently noticed that I lost 2 points of reputation. I clicked on the reputation tab to see why and I came to the conclusion it was connected with a post that I had edited (as a <2K user on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)) that was deleted. This was not the only time I noticed this.

Of course, I came to the conclusion that I should not have wasted my time (and the time of the suggested edit reviewers) editing a post that eventually got deleted (and I fully agree with and accept the loss of reputation).

However, I cannot see any indication from my profile that I made any such suggested edits. So I checked [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and I can see that I have made 13 approved suggested edits which were later deleted together with their posts. But no further details as the PostId leads to a "Page not found" page.

I would like to review those posts to see if there is anything I could learn from them, however, since I cannot see those posts or my suggested edits, there is nothing I can do.

After reading [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253707/1242908) about seeing deleted posts under some conditions, I would like to ask **why an editor cannot see their approved suggested edits that were deleted together with the edited post?**

Comment: I didn't even know you could lose reputation after a post containing an initially approved edit is deleted. If it is approved, why would you lose rep over it later on? That seems unfair.

Comment: @Joachim Here are two links connected with reputation loss: 
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108263/1242908) and
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140817/losing-2-reputation-earned-by-editing-questions-before-2k-rep?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I just noticed in the second link that I can see my reputation loss for suggested edits by clicking on the "show removed posts", however I still cannot see the deleted posts or my suggested edits.

Comment: @Joachim On reflection, it does seems unfair. If the community has an approval process that accepts a suggested edit, then why should the <2K editor be penalised for choosing a poor candidate to edit. The approval process should encourage editors not only to make good substantial edits, but also to choose good edit candidates. It was only recently that I came across this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260302/1242908). I wish I had read that post much earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is annoying, but there is a workaround. You just need the link to the suggested edit itself, which can also be [found via SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1724736/suggested-edits-by-a-given-user). Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32325447 . Admittedly this doesn't give a lot of information to explain why the post was deleted (except maybe for some Roomba auto-deletions—like on any question over 1 year old, with no comments, no answers, no upvotes).

Comment: The workaround is useful. I forked the query you linked to display a list of [deleted suggested edits for a given user on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1810869/deleted-suggested-edits-by-a-given-user). There isn't much information given and I agree that it would be useful to see the original post, the edit history, and the post activity. But this problem should be avoidable by sticking to the advice [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155961/1242908)